# Pick image from camera, gallery,photos, google drive, etc

Tags: android

I implement the following code but found different result on phone kitkat api and marshmallow. Picture as below. Unlike api KitKat, almost all media icon apps can be displayed but why on the API Marshmallow, the google drive icon and other media icon not even appeared out? What correct code should I write in order to make all apis used in android phone can behave the same and console out all media icons like in KitKat? I even tried if i include statement `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)` , in marshmallow, the result is even worse where icon photos and gallery not displayed.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using");
        // Add the camera options.
        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        captureIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { captureIntent });
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

Result:
**a. Marshmallow**
[image]

**b. KitKat**
[image]

Comment: Do not use ACTION_PICK on Marshmallow.  You reversed the two intents.

Comment: And why are you messing around with an extra intent for the camera? Keep your problematic code as small as possible please.